# How to append data to a google spreadsheet?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I have checked various SO questions, and I see that there should be an append method available on service().spreadsheet().values() but that method does not exist on this object for me unlike other SO questions. How do I append data to a google spreadsheet instead of writing over the whole document?

This is the code that I am using which writes over the current document instead of appending to it.

```
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

...

    public static boolean writeToPersistedGoogleDoc(List<FlightBookingRow> rows) throws IOException {

        Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        String valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";

        List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

        for(FlightBookingRow row: rows){
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(row.getTimeBooked());
            list.add(row.getPaidStatus());
            list.add(row.getCostOfTicket());
            list.add(row.getFlightPlan());
            list.add(row.getNumberOfPeople().toString());
            list.add(row.getDepartureDate().toString());
            list.add(row.getReturnDate().toString());
            list.add(row.getCompanyBookedWith());
            values.add(list);
        }




        ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(values);
        UpdateValuesResponse result =
                service.spreadsheets().values().update(PERSISTED_FLIGHT_SHEET, RANGE, body)
                        .setValueInputOption(valueInputOption)
                        .execute();
        System.out.printf("%d cells updated.", result.getUpdatedCells());


        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly out dated dependency in my pom file.

I added this, and then I got access to the append method.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
    <version>v4-rev494-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```